Find partial derivative $\frac{\partial (xyf(xy))}{\partial y}$ given $y=g(x)$.
Given $y=g(x)$,
Find partial derivative $\frac{\partial (xyf(xy))}{\partial y}$.
There are two ways of doing this.

Use chain rule, we get the derivative$=xf(xy)+xyf_y(xy)=xf(xy)+x^2yf'(xy)$.

Substitute the $y=g(x)$ into the formula we get $xg(x)f(xg(x))$, whose partial derivative is zero.


What mistakes did I make?

For your item 2, why do you say the partial derivative of $x g(x) f(xg(x))$ with respect to $g(x)$ is zero?

In the second summand in $1$ just subsitute $y=g(x).$ There is no reason that this term vanishes.

Your partial differentiation treats $x$ and $y$ as independent variables, but $y=g(x)$ asserts a dependency.  Of course you will receive inconsistent results.

But of course substituting $g(x)$ for $y$ after taking a derivative that treats $x$ and $y$ as independent variables will not be the same as making the substitution before the differentiation.
Nor will they be the same as substituting $x:=g^{-1}(y)$ before the differentiation.
$$\begin{align}\left.\dfrac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial y}
\right\vert_{y:=g(x)} &= F^{(0,1)}(x,g(x))\tag 1
\\[3ex] \dfrac{\partial[F(x,y)]_{y:=g(x)}}{\partial y} &= \dfrac{\partial F(x,g(x))}{\partial y}\\&=0\tag 2\\[3ex]\dfrac{\partial[F(x,y)]_{x:=g^{-1}(y)}}{\partial y}&=\dfrac{\mathrm d F(g^{-1}(y),y)}{\mathrm d y} \\&= \dfrac{F^{(1,0)}(g^{-1}(y),y)}{g'(g^{-1}(y))}+F^{(0,1)}(g^{-1}(y),y)\tag 3\end{align}$$
You must decide which is appropriate for your project.

Remark: the third case is often written briefly as
$$\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d y}F(x,y) = \dfrac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x}\dfrac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d y}+ \dfrac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial y}$$
So given $y=g(x)$ then$$\begin{align}\dfrac{\mathrm d xyf(xy)}{\mathrm d y} &=\dfrac{\partial xyf(xy)}{\partial x}\dfrac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d y}+\dfrac{\partial xyf(xy)}{\partial y}\\&= \dfrac{yf(xy)+xy^2f'(xy)}{g'(x)}+xf(xy)+x^2f'(xy)\end{align}$$

what is the meaning of $f'(xy)$? derivative respective to what?

$f$ is a monovariate function.  $f'$ is the derivative with respect to its argument.
